# Categories and Tags returning 404 on the sidebar when using ugly permalinks

Tags: categories, permalinks, tags, sidebar

I am using "ugly" permalinks and they are fine in index.php and single.php. I also have a template called sidebar.php that builds a sidebar when at the article/post level. When clicking categories and tags on the sidebar I am then returned with a 404. The actual format is:

http://localhost/mywebsite/tag/mytag

http://localhost/mywebsite/category/mycategory

As opposed to what I am expecting for ugly permalinks (and it shows in index.php and single.php):

http://localhost/mywebsite/?tag=1

http://localhost/mywebsite/?cat=3

My tags are defined like this:

```
function printTags($tags){
    if ($tags!=false) {
      $return = '';
      foreach ($tags as $i){
        $return .= '<li><a href="' . home_url() . "/tag/" . $i->slug . '">' . $i->name . '</a></li>';
      }
      return $return;
    }
}




function getTags($tagData){
    $tagArray = [];
    if($tagData!=false){
      foreach ($tagData as $i){
        array_push($tagArray, $i->name);
      }
    }
    return $tagArray;
}
```

My HTML/PHP is as follows:

```
function newSuggestion($itemTitle, $sectionSlug, $section, $image, $url, $tags){
    echo "<li class='row class'>
            <div class='col item'>
              <div class='row img-container'>
                <div class='col'>
                  <a href='{$url}'><img src='{$image}' alt='No Image'/></a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class='row anotherclass'>
                <div class='categories-container'>
                  <strong><a href='". home_url() ."/category/". $sectionSlug."'>{$section}</a></strong>
                </div>
                <div class='tags-container'>
                  <ul class='tags'>". printTags($tags) ."</ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class='row title-container'>
                <h2 class='h3'><a href='{$url}'>{$itemTitle}</a></h2>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>";
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thank you

**EDIT1:**

Here is my getPosts function from sidebar.php:

```
    function getPosts($posts, $numSuggestion){

      foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
         if ($post->ID!=get_the_ID() &&  $GLOBALS['currentSuggestion']<$numSuggestion && !in_array($post->ID, $GLOBALS['$alreadySuggested'])){
            $imageUrl = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));

            if ($imageUrl == false){
              $imageUrl = getDefaultImage();
            }
            newSuggestion($post->post_title, get_the_category($post->ID)[0]->slug, get_the_category($post->ID)[0]->name, $imageUrl, get_permalink($post->ID), get_the_tags($post->ID));
            $GLOBALS['currentSuggestion']++;
            array_push($GLOBALS['$alreadySuggested'], $post->ID);
          }
      }
    }
```

**EDIT2:**

I have attempted this:

```
<div class='categories-container'>
                  <strong><a href='". home_url() ."/category/?cat=". $cat_ID."'>{$section}</a></strong>
                </div>
```

But with no success, is that the right direction. Where do I make the modification in order to get the categories URL in the format "home_url/category/?cat=123"?

**EDIT3:**

Not sure I am going towards the right direction, but I have managed to get the right URL, however it returns a 404 (as opposed to categories at article/home level)

I have modified the getPosts function so that `get_the_category` is mapped to the cat_ID rather than the slug (I am not sure that is the right approach):

```
 newSuggestion($post->post_title, get_the_category($post->ID)[0]->cat_ID, get_the_category($post->ID)[0]->name, $imageUrl,
```

then my newSuggestion function has:

```
  <div class='categories-container'>
                  <strong><a href='". home_url() ."/category/?cat=". $sectionSlug."'>{$section}</a></strong>
                </div>
```

Any idea why I am still hitting a 404, while the same URL is functioning in other parts of the site (e.g. home/index or article)?

**EDIT4:**

I finally got the categories working with this:

```
<div class='categories-container'>
                  <strong><a href='". get_term_link( $sectionSlug) . "'>{$section}</a></strong>
                </div>
```

Comment: One thing that stands out right away is that your HTML is missing all of the opening and closing PHP tags, `<?php` and `?>` respectively.

Comment: You should always use the API to generate links to content, like [`get_term_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/).

Comment: @DaveRomsey I have now added the full code for my sidebar.php. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @Milo how/where do you use the get_term_link? Thank you for getting back to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestion for tags, I have gotten categories working.

I have modified the getposts function by mapping the category to the cat_ID, rather than the slug:

```
newSuggestion($post->post_title, get_the_category($post->ID)[0]->cat_ID, get_the_category($post->ID)[0]->name, $imageUrl,
```

Then the NewSuggestion functions works out the categories in this way:

```
<div class='categories-container'>
                  <strong><a href='". get_term_link( $sectionSlug) . "'>{$section}</a></strong>
                </div>
```

The approach works, any suggestion or recommendation on how to improve it is more than welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
home_url() . "/tag/" . $i->slug
```

Use [`get_term_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/) function. It will return the link for the term according with the current configuration:

```
// Assuming $i is a term object
get_term_link( $i->term_id )
```

For example, your `printTags()` function would be:

```
function printTags($tags){
    //Check to see if tags are provided
    if ($tags!=false) {
      $return = '';
      foreach ($tags as $i){
        $return .= '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $i->term_id ) . '">' . $i->name . '</a></li>';
      }
      return $return;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you so much. I am not versed with tags and categories at all and still finding my way. I have made the changes and it works fine. I am stuck with the issue with the categories as per my second edit, not sure how you get the categories to be using the ugly permalinks in the code. Can you help?

Comment: So, I have managed to have the correct URL (see my EDIT3), but I am still getting a 404, while anywhere else the URL is actually working. I think I am getting closer, any idea why this is not working yet?

Comment: I think I got it working using this:

<div class='categories-container'>
                  <strong><a href='". get_term_link( $sectionSlug) . "'>{$section}</a></strong>
                </div>