# How do I retrieve the category ID (ugly permalinks) in my sub-navigation menu?

Tags: categories, theme-development, permalinks

I have recently faced multiple issues with a theme developed with in mind pretty permalinks when moving back to ugly ones (for a number of different reasons). Had issues that I resolved with categories and tags as displayed on my sidebar and also now have the same issue with categories in a custom navigation menu.

Originally, the below code would take me to all the posts whose category is called ‘Amazing’, currently with the use of ugly permalinks (to which I need to stick now for a bunch of reasons) I am returned with a 404 error message. Here is an excerpt of my navigation:

```
<nav class="my-nav-menu">
  <div class="myclass">
    <ul role="navigation" class="mymenuentries">
      <li class="col-clas">
         <a class="myotherclass" href="<?php echo home_url() ?>/category/Amazing">AmazingCategory</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The code will generate this URL:

http://localhost/mywebsite/Amazing

that returns a 404 message, whereas I know that the following will return all the posts associated to that category:

http://localhost/mywebsite/?cat=12

How can I dynamically make sure that the category is fetched by its ID? I am also very much not aware how that piece of code was actually working with pretty permalinks. Can you help?

Thank you

Comment: So you have hard-coded links that you want to replace? I think the answer may be the same as [the one to your other question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/257910/4771).

Comment: Yeah, it is long story, the theme was developed for and worked fine with pretty permalinks, but it is not fine with ugly ones. I have tried the same approach by doing this:

  <a class="myotherclass='". get_term_link( $sectionSlug) . "'>AmazingCategory</a>

but I am getting the wrong category name and id. Please note that my sub-nav is a separate template php than my sidebar.php. I am very much lost as I had no idea why it was actually working fine with pretty permalinks. Any idea how I can change it to pick the right cat/cat id? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`get_term_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/) with the slug, and specify the taxonomy:

```
$cat_slug = 'Amazing';
$taxonomy = 'category';
$cat_link = get_term_link( $cat_slug, $taxonomy );

if ( is_wp_error( $cat_link ) ) {
   echo $cat_link->get_error_message();
} else {
    echo $cat_link;
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you - it works beautifully.